# Нейросети способны выполнять арифметические операции с вероятностной точностью?

Tags: нейронные-сети

То есть всегда будет вероятность ошибки, даже в простых арифметических операциях?

Я нашёл одну работу, но мой уровень слишком низок чтобы её понять.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.08590.pdf

Comment: Понятие "вероятностная точность" - это чье изобретение? Арифметические операции должны выполняться абсолютно точно и давать единственный, точный ответ . Исключение - теория нечетких чисел и теория интервальных вычислений, где "размытость" ответа есть цель. Какое отношение работа имеет к вопросу - не ясно.

Comment: Вы употребляете неправильный термин, применительно к нейронкам. Нейронки выдают не ответ с вероятностной точностью, сам ответ является вероятностным. Условно говоря, на вопрос 2+2 нейронка отвечает 4 с вероятностью 97%. Т.е. ответ на самом деле может быть 3 или 5 в оставшиеся 3%, грубо говоря

Comment: @ArchDemon Я же это и написал в описании!!! Если знаете как сформулировать ответ более правильно - исправьте пожалуйста. Кнопочка "править".

Comment: @passant В описании всё понятно написано. Вы специально придрались к термину и начали меня злобно троллить. За что я на вас и пожалуюсь. Не надо заниматься троллингом.

Comment: Я не могу читать ваши мысли. Я читаю текст, который вы пишите. Я предполагаю, что вы думаете так же как и пишите. Никто вас не пытается троллить. Вам указали на ошибку в формулировке

Comment: @Valera Rybakoff - а в чем злобный троллинг? Вы так и не сказали, что такое "вероятностная точность" между прочим, а уже куда-то жаловаться собрались. Да без проблем.  А на ваш вопрос, кстати, я ответил - ошибок в арифметических операциях быть не должно, а нечеткость - только в тех случаях, о которых я написал.